# How does unification algorithm actually work?

Tags: prolog, unification

I have this Prolog code:

```
bar(b).
bar(c).
baz(c).
```

This query:

```
bar(X), baz(X).
```

returns `X = c`

If I have this program, which is a little bit different:

```
bar(c).
bar(b).
baz(c).
```

On the same query

```
bar(X), baz(X).
```

why does it return

```
X = c;
false
```

Comment: The semicolon means there is a choicepoint, and another choice is being tried (which is "bar(b)"). The "false" means that the 2nd choice failed, leaving you with one answer. Can see the choicepoint using e.g. https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=gtrace/0  There are many ways to prevent choicepoints, once the program has some discernable logic.

Comment: @brebs In the first example why isn't there another choice tried ?

Comment: Prolog goes through the code in vertical order. In the first example, b was first, but b fails with the baz(X) constraint, so Prolog back-tracked to the 2nd bar choice. There was no 3rd choice for bar, hence no choicepoint. An easy way to remove this choicepoint is to use baz_bar(c), i.e. combine the constraints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The computation performed by Prolog to answer a query can be represented as a tree. Prolog searches this tree using a *depth-first strategy*, automatically *backtracking* when it encounters a failure node (or when the user presses the key ';' to get an alternate answer).

During the search, clauses are used in the order they are declared in the program (from the first to the last).

At the end of the search, Prolog displays `false` only if the **last node visited** in the tree is a **failure node**.

So, to understand why Prolog behaves differently in the two indicated cases, you can compare the search trees that Prolog explores in each of them:

- First case:

[image]

- Second case:

[image]

Comment: In the first case is ```b``` analized first because the first fact is ```bar(b)```, and in the second one is ```c``` analized first because the first fact is ```bar(c)``` ?

Comment: @Alex Yes! But beyond that, the first query ends up displaying an answer (since the last node visited in the first tree is a success node), while the second one ends up displaying `false` (since the last node visited in the second tree is a failure node).