# (gnu) Prolog statement with "or" simple example

Tags: prolog, prolog-toplevel

I struggle with a rather simple GNU Prolog example:

I have a file (test.pl)

```
cat(muki).
dog(roti).
frog(frogi).

animal(X) :- dog(X).
animal(X) :- cat(X).
```

When testing it:

- Importing via `['test.pl']`
- `animal(frogi)` returns `no`, as expected
- `animal(muki)` returns `yes`, as expected
- `animal(roti)` returns `true ?` instead of `yes`, which is not what I would expect.

As far as I know this means that prolog is capable to solve `animal` for `roti` but why it does not return yes, just like before?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71361167/how-does-unification-algorithm-actually-work/71362515#71362515.

Comment: @sail0r: nothing specific about GNU here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare with `trace/0`

```
| ?- [user].
compiling user for byte code...
cat(muki).
dog(roti).
frog(frogi).

animal(X) :- dog(X).
animal(X) :- cat(X).

user compiled, 6 lines read - 578 bytes written, 11515 ms

(5 ms) yes
| ?- trace.
The debugger will first creep -- showing everything (trace)

yes
{trace}
| ?- animal(muki).
      1    1  Call: animal(muki) ? 
      2    2  Call: dog(muki) ? 
      2    2  Fail: dog(muki) ? 
      2    2  Call: cat(muki) ? 
      2    2  Exit: cat(muki) ? 
      1    1  Exit: animal(muki) ? 

(2 ms) yes
{trace}
| ?- animal(roti).
      1    1  Call: animal(roti) ? 
      2    2  Call: dog(roti) ? 
      2    2  Exit: dog(roti) ? 
      1    1  Exit: animal(roti) ? 

true ? 

(1 ms) yes
{trace}
| ?- halt.
```

Ok, now swap the two `animal/1` predicates and trace again

```
| ?- [user].
compiling user for byte code...
cat(muki).
dog(roti).
frog(frogi).
animal(X) :- cat(X).
animal(X) :- dog(X).

user compiled, 5 lines read - 578 bytes written, 16421 ms

(12 ms) yes
| ?- trace.
The debugger will first creep -- showing everything (trace)

yes
{trace}
| ?- animal(roti).
      1    1  Call: animal(roti) ? 
      2    2  Call: cat(roti) ? 
      2    2  Fail: cat(roti) ? 
      2    2  Call: dog(roti) ? 
      2    2  Exit: dog(roti) ? 
      1    1  Exit: animal(roti) ? 

(1 ms) yes
{trace}
```

On the second run you can see that a failure was encountered and GNU Prolog had to backtrack. If there is no backtracking and the query is true straightaway, with no alternatives to backtrack through, GNU Prolog will show `true`. If there is backtracking and ultimately the query succeeds, and there exist alternative paths to backtrack though, then GNU Prolog will show `yes` and allow you to enter a `;` to show other solutions. In this case if you were to enter a semi-colon to show other solutions the only other solution is a failure (try it out!)