# Why changing the declaration order changes unification behave?

Tags: prolog

If we declare facts like this:

```
dnp_padrão(1, plural, mos).
dnp_padrão(2, plural, 'is').
dnp_padrão(3, plural, m).

dnp_padrão(1, singular, '').
dnp_padrão(2, singular, s).
dnp_padrão(3, singular, '').
```

And ask prolog:

```
?- dnp_padrão(1, singular, X).
X = ''.
```

Ok, there is only one fact that unifies with this query, but if I ask:

```
?- dnp_padrão(1, plural, X).
X = mos ;
false.
```

Why SWI-Prolog unification tries to search for another fact if there is only one fact that unifies?
Why in the previous question it doesn't?
How does unification work in those cases?

Comment: Due to indexing on the *first* argument, also called "first-argument indexing". Explanation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FZLofckPu4A - can be utilized, at an advanced level, with https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=term_expansion/2

Comment: Please, see an explanation here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71361167/how-does-unification-algorithm-actually-work/71362515#71362515.

Comment: you can just ignore this. the meaning is the same, the difference is only operational, not semantical: `X .OR. False === X`.

Answer (score 0):

From this [documentation](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=glossary):

> Indexing
>
> - Indexing is a technique used to quickly select candidate clauses of a predicate for a specific goal. In most Prolog systems, indexing is done (only) on the first argument of the head. If this argument is instantiated to an atom, integer, float or compound term with functor, hashing is used to quickly select all clauses where the first argument may unify with the first argument of the goal.

That means both your queries `dnp_padrão(1, ...)` filter down to these two facts:

```
dnp_padrão(1, plural, mos).
dnp_padrão(1, singular, '').
```

The query `?- dnp_padrão(1, singular, X).` finds the first one is not a match because of the `plural` argument, shows you the second one, and knows there are no more - no choice point.

The query `?- dnp_padrão(1, plural, X).` finds the first one, shows it to you and leaves a choice point because there are more facts it has not yet looked at.